# Unable to connect to SQL server using Windows Authentication from Java application in Eclipse

Tags: java, dll, sqljdbc

I have 64 bit operating system. I am trying to connect to SQL server from a Java application using windows authentication. When i have used integrated Security=true, I have place the *sqljdbc_auth.dll* in windows/ System 32 folder.

But still I am getting error when I run my Java application on eclipse.

```
WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll
```

Any solutions for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Put it in in your java bin directly, it works from there.

Check in your eclipse's jre directory.